# Curvature of complete conformal metrics on the open unit disk

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, conformal-geometry

Let $D$ be the unit disk in the complex plane, and assume that $g$ is a Riemannian metric on $D$ which is complete and conformal to the standard Euclidean metric. Can it be the case that the Gaussian curvature of $g$ approaches zero as we approach $\partial D$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. Take the metric with length element $\rho(z)|dz|$ where $\rho(z)=(1-|z|)^{-2}$.
It is complete since $\int^1\rho(t)dt=\infty$, and the curvature
$$-\rho^{-2}\Delta\log\rho=\rho^{-4}({\rho'}^2-\rho\rho'')=-2(1-r)^2\to 0,$$
where $r=|z|$ and the primes indicate differentiation with respect to $r$.

Comment: Great example! Is there a limit on the rate at which the curvature can approach zero?

Comment: @user160856: since there is no flat complete metric, there must be some such limit on the rate, but I do not see how to determine it at this moment, even for the metrics depending only on $r$.

Comment: Why does the fact that there is no flat complete metric on the unit disk imply that there must be some limit on the rate?

Comment: @user160856: If I knew I would answer your question in the comment.